# THREE.js (with css3d): Shifting the scene's origin to a corner of the rendering div

Tags: javascript, three.js

We all know that while using three.js to render graphics within a div, the co-ordinates of every object attached to the scene are calculated w.r.t to the origin, being the center of that div of course.

Now, the question: Does three.js provide a method to shift that origin to the top left or any corner of the div, Such that the object co-ordinates can be specified  in a similar manner in css3??